# What is an efficient equivalent in C# for Span<Span<T>>, which does not exist?

Tags: c#, double-pointer, memory-safety, stackalloc

I was porting some older high-speed C++ code to C#, and the existing code made use of a pointer-based double-indirection pattern like this (written here in a C# syntax), using the stack as efficient temporary storage:

```cs
public struct Source {
    public byte* Start;
    public int Count;
}

public struct SourceSet {
    public Source* Start;
    public int Count;
}

Source* sources = stackalloc Source[n*k];
SourceSet* sourceSets = stackalloc SourceSet[n];
```

It populates the `sources` with sets of segments of the data, and populates the `sourceSets` with how many `Source`s are in each set.

The code works fine, but ideally, I would like to convert it to no longer use pointers and `unsafe` — to instead use something memory-safe like this, where each `SourceSet` would be populated by a `.Slice()` of the sources:

```cs
public struct Source {
    public int Start;
    public int Count;
}

Span<Source> sources = stackalloc Source[n*k];
Span<Span<Source>> sourceSets = stackalloc Span<Source>[n];
```

But I can't write that, because `Span<Span<T>>` can't exist in C# — `Span<T>` is a `ref struct` and thus can't be used as the type parameter of another `Span<T>`.  And I can't use `Memory<Memory<T>>` as a replacement, because `stackalloc` only produces a `Span<T>` (or a pointer, but the goal is to avoid pointers).

(And yes, I understand that `Span<Span<T>>` will likely never be added to the language, because it could potentially allow the rules about span lifetimes to be violated.)

So what's a good, efficient equivalent in C# for *safe* double-pointer indirection on the stack, something like `Span<Span<T>>`, but that actually exists?

Comment: How much speed are you willing to give up?  That's why `unsafe` code exists; to trade safety for speed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The initial setup can be expensive, but the resulting data structures are used millions of times in tight inner loops. It can afford a *little* bit of loss, which is why `byte* Start` could be just `int Start`, but not a *lot*. But the question is less about my specific case — I can live with `unsafe` if I have to — than about the general question: What's the best way to do memory-safe double-pointer indirection on the stack in C#?

Comment: Span is a semantic trick to hide a pointer without having to use the *unsafe* keyword.  The compiler ensures that this pointer can't dangle.  It can't do that for pointer-to-pointer.  Fear not, just use a pointer when you need one.

Comment: @HansPassant Like I said, the code works with pointers as written. But I'd really like to have the safety provided by `Span` (or equivalent) if I could get it. The introduction of `Span` in C# showed I could have my cake and eat it too, and now I want more :-)

Comment: [`Memory<T>` is essentially a `Span<T>` without the `ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1?view=net-6.0).

Comment: @RobertHarvey There are a lot of reasons why `Memory<T>` doesn't work. It's not compatible with the return types of `stackalloc`, so to get a `Memory<T>`, you have to use pointers anyway. It doesn't have an indexer. You have to either `Pin` it and get a pointer, or convert it to a `Span` to use it, which have high performance costs if you're iterating over hundreds of `Memory<T>` instances in an inner loop. I looked at using `Memory<T>`, but it's not really a viable alternative.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience squeezing every last cycle out of the CPU, but putting something on the heap isn't _that_ much of a performance hit, is it? Especially when it'll be in L1 cache because you're accessing it millions of times in tight inner loops. Also C++ compilers are a lot different than what C# does. Do benchmarks on the C# code warrant what you're trying to do, or is it a premature optimization?

Comment: @MattThomas Those data structures get hit millions of times in an inner loop that has a fixed total execution budget of about half a millisecond. So... yes: The heap would be effectively unusable. There's a reason the original code was C(++), and it's only because now CPUs have gotten so fast and C# has low-level tools like Span<T> that C# was even a viable option. Since writing this, I've left the original C++ in place, because C# simply couldn't handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Span2D<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/high-performance/span2d):

```
Span2D<byte> span2d = (stackalloc byte[height * width]).AsSpan2D(height, width);
```

Comment: Abstracts a block in memory to be available as _rows_, but doesn't help in using double indirection.